# What steps are required to make ColdFusion websockets work on an AWS VM behind Cloudflare?

Tags: websocket, coldfusion

We have a very similar setup as this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783616/what-steps-are-required-to-make-coldfusion-websockets-work-on-an-azure-vm-behind](https://stackoverflow.com)
with differences noted below.

When our client attempts to connect to the cfws proxy the client (browser Network console) shows an HTTP 101 Upgrade but at the server the proxy repeatedly logs the below errors. What steps am I missing?

Errors logged (wsproxy.log):

2023-12-06 13:16:03.0354 CF WSProxy Log Unable to connector to server proxy port. Make sure websocket proxy is enabled at server.
2023-12-06 13:16:03.0354 CF WSProxy Log Unable to connector to server proxy port. Error code :ConnectionRefused
2023-12-06 13:16:03.0663 CF WSProxy Log Failed getting the connections from connectionpool.
2023-12-06 13:16:03.0944 CF WSProxy Log Received message {"ns":"coldfusion.websocket.channels","type":"welcome","authKey":"[REMOVED FOR POST]","subscribeTo":"my_channel1","appName":"App Name 1"}

Differences:

- CF2023
- AWS instead of Azure,
- We successfully created the external Web proxy per this https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/coldfusion-and-html-5/using-coldfusion-websocket/websocket-enhancements.html
- (wsproxyconfig using an Admin account, folders at <CF_INSTALL_HOME>/config/wsproxy/1 were successfully created).
- Different 8xxx port.
- <cfwebsocket...secure = "false"> vs. <cfwebsocket...secure = "true"> when using ColdFusion Internal Websockets.

Comment: You mentioned cloudflare. Is Websockets enabled there?

Comment: Yes, Websockets is enabled per these steps. The log message received at the wsproxy.log and the HTTP 101 at the client would seem to indicate that Websocket communication is at least reaching the proxy.

Enable WebSockets

Log in to your Cloudflare account Open external link and go to a specific domain.

Go to Network.

For WebSockets, switch the toggle to On.